# Script for automatically generate the html output from headerdoc comments from within Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, documentation, headerdoc

I'm using headerDocs to document my Xcode Project. And I successfully documented my project. but I want to know the **`script`** for **`automatically generate`** the **`html output`** from headerdoc comments from within **`Xcode`**. To the info I know to run the headerdoc and gather it to one main doc via **`Terminal`**. Someone help me with script to run the headerdoc automatically. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add a run script to you build phases of your project target. Create shell script file while generates the headerdoc using headerdoc2html tool. Add this .sh file to run script build phase. Each time when you compile the sources headerdoc will also generate automatically. You can modify the script such that it will generate headerdoc only on release mode.

Documentation to use headerdoc2html is:

Once you have a header containing HeaderDoc comments, you can run the headerdoc2html script to generate HTML output like this:

```
 > headerdoc2html MyHeader.h
```

Apple's documentation [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/usage/usage.html):